# Woocommerce products shortcode doesn't display products out of stock

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I have shortcode, for example:

```
[products ids="123,322,555,645,888"]
```

And it shows only products in stock. Out of stock products are not displayed. Is there a way to display all products (in stock and out of stock) by a shortcode even if there is global woocommerce setting "hide products out of stock" enabled?

I tried to write my own shortcode, but the problem is the same.

Thanks for your suggestions.

EDIT: It also doesn't display variable products, even if variations are in stock.

EDIT 2: Problem is with Woocommerce setting "hide out of stock items from the catalog". I need this option keep enabled globally, except this one shortcode. I tried to modify filter "woocommerce_shortcode_products_query", but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was in the content-product.php template. There were condition "$product->is_visible()" causing the issue.